# Installing or updating a package using the pip in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pip

If I accidentally run any of the following commands to install or update a package using pip in Python 3.x twice, will it install or update that package twice on the machine?

pip install <package_name>

pip install --upgrade <package_name>

After updating a package twice, it says that:

Requirement already satisfied: appnope in ./.pyenv/versions/3.11.0/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from ipykernel) (0.1.3)"

Does this mean I already updated or installed the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command installs the package. Because you have not specified a package version with something like `pip install package-name==1.0.0`, pip will install the package with the latest version.

The second command attempts to upgrade the same package. Because it is installed with the latest version, there is nothing to upgrade. pip will not reinstall packages unless you ask it to.

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package-name>`

pip will also attempt to install dependencies for your packages that may be required for the package you requested.

> Requirement already satisfied: appnope in ./.pyenv/versions/3.11.0/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from ipykernel) (0.1.3)"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means you have already installed or upgraded.